# Can't Delete Sculpt Brushes

Tags: interface

[image]
Can't remove these custom brushes, I've made these by mistake and there appears to be no way of removing them.

They are conflicting with my sculpting learning as it seems like random brushes are being picked.

Please don't say click on and press the "X" as it does nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the *Outliner*, select *Orphan Data*, click on the *Purge* button:

[image]

It will remove all the brushes with a "0" name. To remove the "F" brushes (they have a fake user so that they are saved when you save your file), select them and click on the shield icon. You could also close and open your file, all the "0" brushes should disappear.